# MySQL Function Returns INT(11) but view sets type to BIGINT

Tags: mysql, function, view

I have a simple function that I use occasionally when building views with multiple table joins that prevents null values from being sent to client application.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `NullToInt`(targetVal int(11), defaultValue int(11)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

IF targetVal IS NULL THEN
    RETURN defaultValue;
ELSE
    RETURN targetVal;
END IF;

END
```

The problem is randomly my view definition will show the column using that function as a BIGINT rather than a standard INT.

```
CREATE VIEW `test_view` AS 
SELECT 
    `A`.`a_id`,
    `A`.`a_col_b_fk`,
    NullToInt(`B`.`b_someint`,0) as `b_someint`
FROM `table_a` `A`
LEFT JOIN `table_b` `B` ON `A`.`a_col_b_fk` = `B`.`b_id`;
```

I'm at a loss as I assumed since the function only returns int(11) I have no idea why mysql would assume I wanted a BIGINT

[Image showing both InformationSchema and Query Field Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8naGV.jpg)

The tables columns are defined with INT not BIGINT

[EDIT]
I checked the information_schema.columns and it indicates the correct data type of INT.

Its when you actually execute the view it changes to BIGINT as the image shows.

[EDIT]

I was kind of able to recreate the issue on my home lab
Only instead of my custom function its the built in `IFNULL()`

This is similar to the issue I'm having as the column unexpectedly is converted to BIGINT but it does differ from my original issue. This example, the information.schema matches the output datatype as bigint, however the original issue which is more random and harder to reproduce the information.schema doesn't match the output datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_a` (
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `a_int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `test_db`.`tbl_a` (`a_name`, `a_int`) VALUES ('A', '20');
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`tbl_a` (`a_name`, `a_int`) VALUES ('B', '10');
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`tbl_a` (`a_name`) VALUES ('C');
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`tbl_a` (`a_name`, `a_int`) VALUES ('D', '20');

CREATE VIEW `test_a` AS select `tbl_a`.`a_id` AS `a_id`,`tbl_a`.`a_name` AS `a_name`,ifnull(`tbl_a`.`a_int`,0) AS `a_int` from `tbl_a`;

SELECT * FROM test_a;
```

Comment: Why re-implement `IFNULL()`?

Comment: I tested that view definition as you showed, using MySQL 5.7. Then I queried INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to see the data types of the columns of the view, and it's INT. Why makes you think it's defining the column as BIGINT?

Comment: @BillKarwin I added an image from workbench that shows field types of the view, Also my client application throws type conversion error since it is expecting int32 not int64. It is random, I have the same function used in other views and it returns int as expected.

Comment: @tadman I wasn't aware if IFNULL(), Before this function i would use IF col IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE col  Which is can get confusing to read. I just tried IFNULL and its doing the same thing, returning BIGINT rather than INT.

Comment: It's a handy MySQL-specific function. The alternative is usually `CASE` as that works in a regular `SELECT` as well.

Comment: @tadman your right I was thinking about stored procedures but it would be ```CASE```

Comment: Nope, I tried selecting from the view in MySQL Workbench, then select the "Field types" tab for the result set. It still says type INT.

Comment: Anyway, I suppose there could be a view expression that does some arithmetic on the INT function result such that it must upgrade the data type to BIGINT. Like if you have any arithmetic expression that could return a value greater than the maximum signed INT, it must use BIGINT. Example: `NullToInt() * 2`

Comment: @BillKarwin That would make sense but the views are defined as outlined above, no arithmetic performed, just checking for null. I have a feeling its a bug but I usually don't like blaming the software without fully vetting my problem first.